# Unable to update Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

I tried to update my system this morning, running Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy, and get this message.

```
The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

I searched the internet and these pages but can't find out how to get around this warning. It's not a PPA and when I run `grep -r -i ppa /etc/apt/` there is nothing that matches the name of the offending repository.

There is also nothing in the Software Updater that matches. I tried switching different main servers, but with no success. This is the first time this has happened and I have been running 22.04 for months now.

Update:
These are the first four lines output by `sudo apt-update`

```
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release                                                                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Get:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish InRelease [48.9 kB]
```

Comment: 'Impish' is 21.10, not 22.04. Having active impish sources suggests that your release-upgrade to 22.04 was incomplete or done improperly.

Comment: I ended up just doing a fresh installation of 22.04 Jammy and that fixed the problem. I think the previous upgrade didn't execute properly.